# Scala typemismatch in spark map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I write an method to load data from mongodb(version:3.4) to spark(use mongo-spark-connector, version:2.2.1), and my spark version is 2.2.0, scala version is 2.11.8. I want to use a function called resultHandler accept org.bson.Document and return T to etl mongodb raw data.

```
def loadFromMongodb[T1: ClassTag](
                                    mongoUri: String,
                                    spark: SparkSession,
                                    pipeline: Seq[Document]
                                  )(
                                    resultHandler: Document => T1
                                  ): RDD[T1] = {
    spark
      .sparkContext
      .loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> mongoUri)))
      .withPipeline(pipeline) // filter push down
      .map(doc => resultHandler(doc))
  }
```

When i compile it, i got a type mismatch error in here:

```
Error:(50, 33) type mismatch;
   found   : T1
   required: org.bson.Document
      .map(doc => resultHandler(doc))
```

I don't know why.

Please help me, Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code here, not only the link to image of it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. Please add your actual code to the question, dont use images. The errormessage does makes things pretty clear by the way. The "map" function expects a parameter of `org.bson.Document` while you delievered a object of type `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are too smart for the mongo-spark-connector or at least there is a conflict between you being smart and mongo-spark-connector being smart with its implicit `DefaultsTo` magic.

I didn't dig up the whole story but it looks like the fact that you provided your `T1` with an implicit evidence of `ClassTag[T1]` is enough to make the line

```
.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> mongoUri)))
```

to be interpreted as

```
.loadFromMongoDB[T1](ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> mongoUri)))
```

which is obviously not what you want. The simplest way to fix your error is to explicitly type it with `Document` as in

```
def loadFromMongodb[T1: ClassTag](
                                   mongoUri: String,
                                   spark: SparkSession,
                                   pipeline: Seq[Document]
                                 )(
                                   resultHandler: Document => T1
                                 ): RDD[T1] = {
  spark
    .sparkContext
    // specify [Document] explicitly
    .loadFromMongoDB[Document](ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> mongoUri)))
    .withPipeline(pipeline) // filter push down
    .map(doc => resultHandler(doc))
```

}